# Reference Vector destroyed by pushback to another Vector

Tags: c++, vector, reference, delaunay

it encountered the following problem:

```
vector<pair<float,float> Copy_Vec (const vector<pair<float,float> &v1)
{
     vector<pair<float,float> ret_vec;
     for(size_t var=0; var < v1.size(); var++)
      {
          pair<float,float> p = v1[var];
          ret_vec.pushback(p);
      }
     return ret_vac;
}
```

Actually destroys the reference to v1, after the pushback operation, the vector v1 changes, how does this happen?

actually that's the code

```
vector< Triangle > Track_Finder::Create_Triangle_Tree(const delaunator::Delaunator &delauny)
{
    Triangle triangle;
    vector< Triangle > ret_tree;
    for(size_t var=0; var < delauny.triangles.size(); var+=3)
    {
      vector<pair<float,float>> vec_p;
      vec_p.resize(3);
      pair<float,float> p;
        p.first =(float) delauny.coords[2 * delauny.triangles[var]];        //tx0
        p.second=(float) delauny.coords[2 * delauny.triangles[var] + 1];    //ty0
        vec_p[0]=p;
        p.first =(float) delauny.coords[2 * delauny.triangles[var + 1]];    //tx1
        p.second = (float) delauny.coords[2 * delauny.triangles[var + 1] + 1];//ty1
        vec_p[1]=p;
        p.first =(float) delauny.coords[2 * delauny.triangles[var + 2]];    //tx2
        p.second =(float) delauny.coords[2 * delauny.triangles[var + 2] + 1]; //ty2
        vec_p[2]=p;
        ret_tree.push_back(Triangle(vec_p));
    }
    return ret_tree;
}
```

when reserving the reference to delauny gets destroyed/corrupted

Comment: That seems very unlikely. Please post a [mcve] that exhibits the behaviour you mention.

Comment: This is not real code.  What is `pushback`?  Why are you typing in code, when you could have easily copy and pasted your actual code?

Comment: Why do you need this function at all? Vectors can already be copied in the normal manner, which is also more efficient than this.

Comment: _"Actually destroys the reference to v1, after the pushback operation, the vector v1 changes"_ What do you mean with that? Also those sound like two different things. Does the reference get destroyed (what does that mean?) or does `v1` change? A good way to clarify what you mean is to create a [MRE]. Please read through the linked page, but in short: its a piece code we can copy & paste, hit run and reproduce your error.

Comment: It's not possible that call to `std::vector::reserve()` manipulates memory owned by another object. Either your access to `delauny` is wrong, or that library is utterly broken and `delauny` has data in memory it doesn't own (both are Undefined Behaviour). Did you step through your code with a debugger?

Comment: The first code snippet contains syntax errors and has nothing to do with the actual problem as shown by the second code snippet. I would suggest removing the first one

Comment: `vec_p.reserve(3);` does not change the size of the vector - it's still empty. Assigning to its non-existent elements has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen accessing the vector out of bounds (as this code does) causes undefined behaviour, which might seem to trash memory of another object

Comment: when changing to resize it doesn't change or using just pushback

Comment: well I solved it by copying the delauny coords vector to another vector.. somehow it works now

Comment: @Prostyle1337 *somehow it works now* -- You need to know why it fixed the problem, else it isn't a fix.  It is a "hope and pray".

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

vector<pair<float,float> > Copy_Vec (const vector<pair<float,float> > &v1)
{
     vector<pair<float,float> > ret_vec;
     for(size_t var=0; var < v1.size(); var++)
      {
          pair<float,float> p = v1[var];
          ret_vec.push_back(p);
      }
     return ret_vec;
}

int main()
{

  vector<pair<float,float> > a= {{1,1},{2,2} ,{3,3}};  

  vector<pair<float,float> > b = Copy_Vec(a); 

  for(const auto & it : b)
  {
      std::cout << it.first << " : " << it.second << "\n";
  }

  for(const auto & it : a)
  {
      std::cout << it.first << " : " << it.second << "\n";
  }
}
```

```
output : 
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 3
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 3
```

nothing was destroyed.

Comment: @Prostyle1337 if this did not solve your problem then please don't give it the green tick